# When fine-tuning a pre-trained Model, how does tensorflow know that the base_model has been changed?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, transfer-learning

Ng's Convolutional Neural Network class's Week 2 Lab on using Transfer Learning with MobileNetV2 (summary: https://github.com/EhabR98/Transfer-Learning-with-MobileNetV2) and an additional tutorial (https://blog.roboflow.com/how-to-train-mobilenetv2-on-a-custom-dataset/) both begin like this:

```
base_model = tf.keras.applications.MobileNetV2(input_shape=IMG_SHAPE, include_top=False, weights='imagenet')
base_model.trainable = False
```

They then proceed to add a pooling layer(s), a Dropout layer and a Dense 1-unit layer to the end, apply a BinaryCrossentropy loss and some kind of optimizer, then train it on some custom data that has been inputted. Lets call this custom model "`model2`" as Ng's lab does

Here's what my the Coursera class model looks like, its important to include here because the variable `base_model` is called in two different closures throughout the Coursera lab (*previous to this* it was called outside of a method, as `base_model = tf.keras.applications.MobileNetV2(input_shape=IMG_SHAPE, include_top=True, weights='imagenet'); base_model.trainable= False`)

```
def alpaca_model(image_shape=IMG_SIZE, data_augmentation=data_augmenter())
    input_shape = image_shape + (3,0)
    base_model = tf.keras.applications.MobileNetV2(input_shape=input_shape, include_top=False, weights='imagenet')
    base_model.trainable = False
    inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=input_shape)
    x = data_augmentation(inputs)
    x = preprocess_input(x)
    x = base_model(x, training=False)
    x = tfl.GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
    x = tfl.Dropout(0.2)(x)
    prediction_layer = tfl.Dense(1)
    outputs = prediction_layer(x)
    model = tf.keras.Model(inputs, outputs)
    return model

model2 = alpaca_model()
base_learning_rate = 0.001
initial_epochs = 5
model2.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=base_learning_rate), loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True), metrics=["accuracy"])
history = model2.fit(train_dataset, validation_data=validation_dataset, epochs=initial_epochs)
```

This performs OK, getting as much as 80% accuracy

Fine tuning -- Now in both the course lab and the tutorial, they then proceed to "unfreeze" some of the last layers of the internal network so that they can be trained, like so:

```
fine_tune_at = 120

base_model = model2.layers[4] #totally separate question, but I would love to hear in comments, what this does exactly. It is difficult to Google this.
base_model.trainable = True

print("#/layers in base model: ", len(base_model.layers))

for layer in base_model.layers[:fine_tune_at]:
    layer.trainable = False

loss_function = tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentrop(from_logits=True)
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=base_learning_rate*0.1)
metrics = ['accuracy']

fine_tune_epochs = 5
total_epochs = initial_epochs + fine_tune_epochs
```

***Up until this point, I'm satisfied, I can clearly see what is going on, but then:***

```
model2.compile(loss=loss_function,optimizer=optimizer,metrics=metrics)
history_fine = model2.fit(train_dataset, epochs=total_epochs, initial_epoch=history.epoch[-1], validation_data = validation_dataset)
```

This leads to a marked improvement in results. Which confused me, I was very much expecting `base_model` to get passed in somehow. I didn’t imagine that altering some other variable that hasn’t been passed into or been initially called would come into play.

***So given all of that context, the question is:*** How is altering the `base_model` affecting `model2`?

If the above example from the Coursera lab is as confusing to you as it is to me, the example shown on https://blog.roboflow.com/how-to-train-mobilenetv2-on-a-custom-dataset/ as mentioned above is much simpler and contains much less ambiguity as `base_model` is defined only once. Regardless, the same dynamic applies and I'm equally confused on both. Thanks again for your time

Answer (score 1):

Your

> totally separate question, but I would love to hear in comments, what this does exactly.

The following list get the MobileNetV2 model:

```
base_model = model2.layers[4]
```

Why 4? Because the first layer is the input, the second layer is the data augmentation (a Sequential model), the third and fourth layers are for image preprocessing (divide by 127.5 and subtract -1 to have values between -1 and 1), the fifth layer is MobileNetV2 (index 4). The other layers are your top-net.

> How is altering the base_model affecting model2

During the first pass (transfer learning), all layers of MNv2 are frozen, so weights and biases remain intact. Whereas for the second pass (fine tuning), the last convolution layers (block 13 to 16 and last Conv2D) are now unfrozen so that the model can modify the weights and bias of the base model. Therefore, the following layers will be changed during training.

To view the full model summary with nested models, use:

```
>>> model2.summary(line_length=125, expand_nested=True, show_trainable=True)
```

Comment: Are you saying here that by modifying base_model (a nested model) I affect model2? Also thank you for answering the side question. I hope my asking it and you answering it helps someone else too

Comment: Yes because your top head (classification network) depends on the base model.

Comment: Could you point me in the direction of some documentation or other material to help me understand how this happens? It seems almost like it is using `base_model` as a global variable

Answer (score 0):

I'll go ahead and post an answer that speaks to (the problem with) Professor Ng's Convolution Neural Network, Week 2 Assignment, "Transfer Learning with MobileNet", with the hope that other students might find this answer and realize that they are not crazy and that the Lab was poorly coded.

I'm not sure how it (appears to work) on Jupyter, but the main reason I was having problems with this lab was that `base_model` was defined several times within the lab. It should have only been defined once. Even worse, the base_model was *redefined* inside the `alpaca_model()` function, but that's not accessible outside the closure of the function. I'm not in the industry, but that is just plain terrible coding to redefine a variable inside a method that's already been defined then call it again outside of the method.

Once I took `base_model` out of the function, defining it beforehand, everything works perfectly not just on the computer, but in my head.

Comment: I'm not agree with you. The function creates a full model with the nested based model which is a good practice. After that, you will be able to retrieve this base model => the only caveat here is the hardcoded layer position (4). It can be better to parse layers until you catch the layer named MobileNetV2 to find the base model. The outer base model variable is a pointer to the inner layer of your Alpaca model. What you do on this variable have an impact on Alpaca model.

Comment: @Corralien The problem is that if you define the `base_model` only within the function you can't call it from outside the function. Redefining `base_model` inside the function assuming it has already been defined is at best, superfluous. I don't mean to sound cavalier I'm just wrestling for an understanding here with regard to the Python programming aspect

Comment: Why do you say "redefining", I would say "define". The only way to create your classification model should be the `alpaca_model` function. From the returned model, you can retrieve `base_model` when you need it for fine tuning. Do you have any use case where do you need to use `base_model` independently of `alpaca_model`?

Comment: @Corralien  Not in this case certainly, its just a lab exercise. And I don't mind defining `base_model` for the first time inside of the `alpaca_model` function but would be unable to call it unless the function returned the `base_model` (which in the lab, it does not)